# Home Page Content Skewed to Left

Tags: html, css, centering, frontpage

[www.SportsAntiques.com](http://www.sportsantiques.com)
When I look at my home page on my laptop or android it looks fine. But when I look at it on large monitor it's all skewed to the left. Can someone take a look at my source code and tell me where the problem is.My site above. I built the site with FrontPage 2000 and have shared borders if that makes any difference. thanks so much

Comment: It is hard to help you with a bug in your code when the question *does not include any of the buggy code*.

Comment: Hi George...Ok I tried to post all my code but I got this notice: "too long by 790397 characters"...I was thinking you would right click my home page and read the source code

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That code should be… **Minimal** – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, there are two `<div>` elements with the `id="fb-root"` that have style of `width: 987`:

```
<td valign="top" width="24"></td>
<td valign="top">
  <div id="fb-root" style="width: 987; height: 48274">
    <div id="fb-root" style="width: 987; height: 58405">
       <p align="center" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0">&nbsp;
```

For large screens, that width constrains the width of the center column. Remove tbose constraints and the column will expand to fill the large screen.

Comment: Ok I deleted only the "987" in both lines and republished the page...wasn't sure if I was suppose to delete the whole line...I will be at a large monitor later this evening and will see how it looks...BTW when I look at my HTML view...above my title at the top of my home page are three tiny squares...one in the center and one on each side...that area seems to be where the 987 widths were...I don't know what those little square dots are for and suspect they don't need to be there...I'm afraid to delete anything in html view...since I don't know what I'm doing...I use FrontPage 2000 as my editor

Comment: georgeawg...thank you so much...yes that straightened out the problem...-Chip